# ACCESS DSUM For a Running Total

Tags: database, function, ms-access

I am trying to use the DSUM function to get a Running Sum of Payments made by customers.  I am looking at payment history across 45 months.  I have an ID column that has a unique Number customer id + the month number /(45 +1).  Therefore, every customer has a unique number in between its customer number and its customer number plus 1 that associates with the payment month.

I am trying to get a DSUM so it sums every ID that is equal to the the current month ID and greater than the Customer Number.

I can get it so that it can get a running sum across all customers if I ascend the customer numbers; however, I want the total to restart at every customer.  Can you tell me what I need to adjust in my formula?

CFRef is the column of Customer month reference in the Ordered CF table. Monthpmt is the sum field in the CF table.

cfr is the relative Customer Month field I have in the current query table that I am trying to match to.

`PmtTot: DSum("Monthpmt","TestOrderedCF","CFRef<=" & [cfr] And "CFRef>=" & [CustNum] And "CFRef=" & [CFref])`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is wrong. Why would CFRef be compared to cfr and CustNum? Perhaps you mean:

`PmtTot: DSum("Monthpmt", "TestOrderedCF", "cfr<=" & [cfr] & " AND CustNum=" & [CustNum] & " And CFRef=" & [CFref])`

If fields are text type, then need apostrophe delimiters: `" AND CustNum='" & [CustNum] & "' AND`

Probably also need to take into account the year as well as month.

Instead of DSum(), might be able to get desired output by using report Sorting & Grouping and textbox RunningSum property.